# SQL integrity constraints with 'NOT' in front

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm having a difficult time understanding the integrity constraints for these statements
Given the statement

> "If age is under 5 years, then price must be over $5000"
>   the following are the IC's

```
CHECK (NOT (age < 5 AND price <= 5000)) 

CHECK (NOT (age >=5 OR price > 5000)
```

> and this statement as well
>   "If type is 'SUV' then the price must be over $10000 but less than $30000"

```
CHECK (NOT (type = 'SUV' AND (price <=10000 OR price >= 30000"

CHECK (((type<> 'SUV') OR (price > 10000 AND price < 30000))
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the 'NOT' is put in front of the IC's as well as the <>('not equal') in the last one. It seems like it negates what the constraint is supposed to be. "CHECK (NOT (age >=5 OR price > 5000)" seems like it should be( age <=5 or price> 5000). "CHECK (((type<> 'SUV') OR (price > 10000 AND price < 30000))." This confuses me because it is saying "type is not equal to SUV, or the price is greater than 10,000 and price is less than 30,000." shouldn't it be type is equal to SUV AND then the second part?

Comment: See [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for the general principle between such "negated" logic conditions. (Remember that SQL has tri-valued logic, but that only applies if there are NULL values present.)

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints, so that tag seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic boolean boolean logic.  The following do the same thing:

```
CHECK (NOT (age >= 5 AND price < 5000) )
CHECK (age < 5 OR price >= 5000)
```

And both of these implement the constraint as you describe it:  if age < 5 then price >= 5000.

The `NOT` is simply there because some people understand this condition as saying that you cannot have both age >= 5 and price < 5000.